# Logs indicating that htaccess URL rewriting is selectively not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use `.htaccess` to enable url rewriting on my php site to provide prettier urls, and they work well. However, in `error_log`, now and then I notice chains of 3-4 logs at about the same time and nearly the same address trying to visit a rewritten url and failing because of `File does not exist:` errors. I want to understand what is happening here. Is there a certain way to access the server that bypasses my `htaccess` based rewriting somehow? Could this be a case of a web crawler/robot

edit: These accesses seem to be from facebook, refreshing its cache i guess.

error_log

```
May 24 21:54:09 ip-10-128-77-197 error_log: [Sat May 24 13:54:09 2014] [error] [client 173.252.100.115] File does not exist: /home/ec2-user/appname/current/public/venue, referer: http://www.domainname.com/venue/VenueName?match=134&fb_locale=zh_TW
May 24 21:54:09 ip-10-128-77-197 error_log: [Sat May 24 13:54:09 2014] [error] [client 173.252.100.115] File does not exist: /home/ec2-user/appname/current/public/venue, referer: http://www.domainname.com/venue/VenueName?match=134&fb_locale=zh_TW
May 24 21:54:09 ip-10-128-77-197 error_log: [Sat May 24 13:54:09 2014] [error] [client 173.252.100.112] File does not exist: /home/ec2-user/appname/current/public/venue, referer: http://www.domainname.com/venue/VenueName?match=134&fb_locale=zh_TW
```

Access_log - sample, about the same time

```
173.252.100.112 - - [24/May/2014:13:54:09 +0000] "GET /venue/img/twit1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 301 "http://www.domainname.com/venue/VenueName?match=134&fb_locale=zh_TW" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
173.252.100.112 - - [24/May/2014:13:54:09 +0000] "GET /venue/img/website.png HTTP/1.1" 404 303 "http://www.domainname.com/venue/VenueName?match=134&fb_locale=zh_TW" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
```

my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^venue/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ bar.php?url_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: yes to both of your questions.

Comment: @CreativeMind you dont say! can you point me to some documentation about this? Any way to prevent this? i.e i want robots to see the proper page

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with your own computer. Go to the url this client goes to. If that doesn't give that problem, or you aren't sure what the url is this client tries to access, search through your access log with the client ip that triggered this error. Without information about the rules you are using, or what url is producing this error, this question cannot really be answered.

Comment: @Sumurai8 You are right, a look at the access log suggests that this is by facebook. Let me post some samples in the questions

Comment: @Sumurai8 Ive added my logs and my htaccess. The url in question works fine from my browser

Comment: Trying this URl on the [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) triggers a huge list of 404s as well, but it seems to parse it fine...

Comment: Those entries seem to suggest there are links to `www.example.com/venue` (without anything behind it). The file `venue` does not exist in that particular directory. I would suggest opening Google Chrome, then it's dev console. Go to the network tab and open `http://www.domainname.com/venue/VenueName?match=134&fb_locale=zh_TW`. Look if any resources return a 404 error. If that is not the case, look if there are any url's on that page that link to a venue without a venuename.

Comment: Adding `R=301` to the options in the end seems to fix this, but it also causes the browser to show the actual url rather than the `venue/` so id rather not use it

Comment: @Sumurai8 no 404s on the browser. `venue` exists only in the `.htaccess` file, it is not mentioned anywhr else

Comment: Do you have any relative url's in your page that it tries to load from the wrong path because you have a fancy url in the url bar?

Comment: @Sumurai8 i do have relative urls on the page, and they work fine when using the browser. They are relative to the root, but facebook seems to see them as relaive to `venue`